# perform more than 1 data operation using for loop - Node js

Tags: sql, node.js, for-loop

I am updating more than two records, in the SQL database.
Actually, I am getting an array of data in JSON format.

I have written query in for loop, but it sends error.
here is code

```
app.post("/editDeviceLocation", (req, res) => {
  var data_array = [];
  try {
    var device_data = req.body.nameValuePairs;

    var total_device_data = device_data.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < total_device_data; i++) {
      db.select(
        "mytag_device",
        "device_mac_address",
        `device_mac_address = '${device_data[i].device_mac_address}'`,
        (data) => {
          // console.log(data_array);
          res.send(data_array);
        }
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({ success: 0, data: error, message: "Error Occured" });
  }
});
```

Here is data to be send

```
{
    "nameValuePairs":[
    {
    "device_mac_address":"FF:FF:97:03:45:51",
    "user_id":"2",
    "device_lat":"72.7602536",
    "device_long":"21.1481166",
    "time":"2021-03-01 16:29:20"
    },
    {
    "device_mac_address":"FF:FF:97:03:45:511",
    "user_id":"2",
    "device_lat":"72.7602536",
    "device_long":"21.1481166",
    "time":"2021-03-01 16:29:20"
    }
    ]
    
}
```

Error

```
D:\MyTag\MyTag\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)        
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\MyTag\MyTag\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the response outside of the loop after the array has been filled with the data that you want to send.

```
app.post("/editDeviceLocation", (req, res) => {
**var data_array = [];**
try {
var device_data = req.body.nameValuePairs;

var total_device_data = device_data.length;
for (let i = 0; i < total_device_data; i++) {
  db.select(
    "mytag_device",
    "device_mac_address",
    `device_mac_address = '${device_data[i].device_mac_address}'`,
    (data) => {
      // console.log(data_array);
      // res.send(data_array);
         **data_array.push(data);**
    }
  );
}
} catch (error) {
res.send({ success: 0, data: error, message: "Error Occured" });
}
 **res.send(data_array);**
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using express.
Then the res.send() cannot be done multiple times over an api.
populate a array and do res.send outside the loop so that it is not called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

As you have multiple request you should do something like this:

```
app.post("/editDeviceLocation", (req, res, next) => {

  const allRequest  = [];
  const device_data = req.body.nameValuePairs;
  const total_device_data = device_data.length;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < total_device_data; i++) {
    let req = db.select(
      "mytag_device",
      "device_mac_address",
      `device_mac_address = '${device_data[i].device_mac_address}'`);
    allRequest.push(req) // register all promises in an array
  }
  
    Promises.all(allRequest).then(data => {
     // data will be an array and give you results in same manner 
     // data[0]; // for first one
     // here you can send data to the user
     res.send(data);
    }).catch(e => console.log(e);
          next(e);
       )
  
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some

```
app.post("/editDeviceLocation", (req, res) => {
  var data_array = [];
  try {
    var device_data = req.body.nameValuePairs;
    var total_device_data = device_data.length - 1;
    for (let i = 0; i <= total_device_data; i++) {
      db.select(
        "mytag_device",
        "device_mac_address",
        `device_mac_address = '${device_data[i].device_mac_address}'`,
        (data) => {
          try {
            if (data.status == 1 && data.data.length > 0) {
              if (
                data.data[0].device_mac_address ==
                `${device_data[i].device_mac_address}`
              ) {
                db.update(
                  "devicelocations",
                  `device_lat = '${device_data[i].device_lat}',device_long = '${device_data[i].device_long}',last_known_time = '${device_data[i].last_known_time}'`,
                  `device_mac_address = '${device_data[i].device_mac_address}' and user_id = '${device_data[i].user_id}'`,
                  (data) => {
                    data_array.push(data);
                    console.log(i + "/" + total_device_data);
                    if (i == total_device_data) {
                      res.send({
                        status: 1,
                        data: data_array,
                        message: "successfully Updated",
                      });
                    } else {
                      console.log("this is not last loop" + i);
                    }
                  }
                );
              } else {
                res.send({ status: 0, data: [], message: "No Data Found" });
              }
            } else {
              res.send({ status: 0, data: [], message: "No Data Found" });
            }
          } catch (error) {
            res.send({ status: 0, data: [], message: "Erro Found" });
          }
        }
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({ success: 0, data: error, message: "Error Occured" });
  }
});
```